# How to find previous months using current month in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I want to find the Previous month list using Current month.Eg Current month is June -2020 so i want to find the previous month list of june (jan -feb-mar -apr-may-june)in asp .net C#.

```
 DateTime dt = Globalization.GetShortDateTime.Month;
 DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);//This will give just only one previous month eg june.
```

But I want to find all the previous month of current month and want to store in list. Any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this.Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not iterating from month 1 to current month ?

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
var now = DateTime.Now;
for (var i = 1; i <= now.Month; i++) {
    //Current year, computed month, day 1, 12:00:00
    var date = new DateTime(now.Year, i, 1, 12, 0, 0);
    dates.Add(date);
}
```

If what you want is the month name, use this instead:

```
var dates = new List<string>();
var now = DateTime.Now;
for (var i = 1; i <= now.Month; i++) {
    //Current year, computed month, day 1, 12:00:00
    var date = new DateTime(now.Year, i, 1, 12, 0, 0);
    dates.Add(date.ToString("MMMM"));
}
```

Comment: this code will bring the answer like 01-01-2020 12:00:00.In this how i bring the month name and also just  the month value

Comment: By using `DateTime.ToString` and using the correct format string. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1.
In your case, what you want is `date.ToString("MMMM")`

Comment: the value  coming correctly i want month value and also name please

Comment: I think you now have all the information you need to do it yourself